# Saving derived class in a variable with base class as static type

Tags: c++, inheritance

I've been looking everywhere on the internet and didn't find any decent answer to following problem.
The code:

```
class P {
 public:
  virtual void play() = 0;    
};

class A: public P {
  public:
  void play() {  };
};

P myVar= A();
```

The last line gives following error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type 'Song'

Although, class A overrided the play()-method and I'm allocating an object of class A instead of P, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: *C++ is not Java...*

Comment: Try `P and myVar = A();`.

Comment: @Brian Then at least give an answer instead of just flaming around with non-helpfull statements...

Comment: Someone else is going to give you the specific answer for this question but my advice is to forget everything you learned from Java and learn C++ from a good book. There is a list of good books here on Stack Overflow. I promise you this is real advice, not passive aggression.

Comment: @Domien: Brian's advice is good. Not all good advice needs to be constructive; sometimes it's just useful to know what not to do, or what not to think. (If you ever had a teenage daughter, you might remember guidance you gave that was non-constructive yet binding.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are trying to make an object `P myVar` that [slices off](https://stackexchange.com/) the additional implementation in `A` by copying the object into `P`.

You cannot do that with "value" objects; you need a pointer or a reference for that. A solution based on built-in C++ pointers looks like this:

```
P *myPtrVar = new A();
... // Use myPtrVar here
delete myPtrVar;
```

A solution based on smart pointes looks like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<P> mySmartPtrVar(new A());
```

The advantage of using [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) is that you do not need to call `delete`: the object will be deallocated as soon as `mySmartPtrVar` is out of scope.

Comment: Thank you, that will do it. Although I'd like to avoid pointers as much as possible.

Comment: @Domien You can use a reference, too. However, if you are looking to "map" the concepts that you know from Java onto C++, all non-primitives of Java would correspond to a pointer in C++.